# Similar Matrices Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

I was confused by the formula for similar matrices. The book says $A = S^{-1} B S$ if $A$ and $B$ are similar. But I'm wondering if $S B S^{-1}$ makes a difference at all? Which formula should I stick to in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S^{-1}BS=(S^{-1})B(S^{-1})^{-1}$, which is of the form $PBP^{-1}$, so without loss of generality we can assume $S^{-1}BS$.